# sed command in groovy pipeline

Tags: sed, jenkins-pipeline

I am using sed command in groovy script in Alfred pipeline.

Following is the sed command that i am trying to execute but get error unexpected token `'('`

```
sh "echo \"sed -i s/LOBCODE IN ([^)]*/LOBCODE IN (${CCLobcode}/ig /bidata/testing/dma_if/sqlfile_if/incoming/${listvalue}_${database}/*.sql\" >> ./ssh_dma_script"
```

I am basically substituting any thing that is passcode to LOBCODE with user defined ($ccLOBCODE) value.

and exlcuing the closing bracket. `( ^) )`

`for ex : LOBCODE in (1002,1003,1009) will get replaced by LOBCODE in (1007). (assuming 1007 is going to be value passed in **ccLOBCODE)`

thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Can you post the current output for "./ssh_ma_script" to that it will be possible to evaluate for additional problems. Hard to tell what is going wrong based on the current information. Answer below assumes no additional errors other than the 'unexpected token ...'

Answer (score 0):

When executing REGEXP to sed it is always better to wrap the REGEXP in quotes, as many of the special characters that are used in the REGEXP have special meaning to the shell. The safe thing is the single quote.

In this case, the RE has dynamic part ($CCLobcode, which is spelled also as ccLOBCODE in the question), which will require some escaping, otherwise it will not get replaced with the run time value.

Note also that REGEXO was modified to replace ALL characters after the parenthesis, until the the ')', and not just the first: `([^)*]`.

```
sh "echo \"sed -i \"s/LOBCODE IN ([^)*]/LOBCODE IN (${CCLobcode}/ig\" /bidata/testing/dma_if/sqlfile_if/incoming/${listvalue}_${database}/.sql\" >> ./ssh_dma_script"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't find any pragmatic benefit to say in a messy way as:

```
sh "echo \"sed ..."
```

instead of:

```
echo "sed ..."
```

In addition, `sh string` will not work without the `-c` option.

Would you please try the following:

```
echo "sed -i 's/LOBCODE IN ([^)]*/LOBCODE IN (${CCLobcode}/ig' '/bidata/testing/dma_if/sqlfile_if/incoming/${listvalue}_${database}/'*.sql" >> ./ssh_dma_script
```

Please remember to quote the `sed` command.